# Sorted Float Vectors for Scatter Plotting (C++ / QCustomPlot)

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

**Questions:**

1 - Sort multiple float vectors in the same order (keeping correspondance)

2 - QCustomPlot (QCP) plots ONLY outer boundary of a scatter plot.

(answering either of these 2 questions would solve my problem)

**Situation:**

I have 3 vectors for plotting:

```
std::vector<float> x, y;
std::vector<int> hits;
```

The resulting plot is a hit or miss scatter plot. The resulting plot is used by QCustomPlot's curve, which ends up as a circular "scribble." It just needs to look similar to a circle with no "scribbling" inside. I need this plot to overlay over another plot.

I don't have much control over the initial order of `x`, `y`, or `hits`.

`x` and `y` are sorted in a traditional grid indexing:

```
x = -8, -8, -8, -8, -8,  -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, ... 8
y = -8, -4,  0,  4,  8,  -8, -4,  0,  4,  8, ... 8
```

The `hits` are based on wether (let's just say archer's arrow) a hit was successful based on a range and speed of a fast target (let's just say bird).

The resulting plot is the outer boudary of hits based on the bird as a center reference.

The data vectors can be very large.

**Method 1:** I can calculate range and angle. Then doing a sort on float vectors: Sort the angles in order, so that when QCustomPlot plots the outer boundary without 'scribbles' inside. However, I need to know how to keep the corresponding `x` & `y` values together based on sorting the `angle`.

```
// Make range and angle vectors for sorting
std::vector<float> range, angle;
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i {

    float r = sqrt(x[i]*x[i] + y[i]*y[i]);
    range.push_back(r);

    float a = 0;
    if(y < 0)
        a = -acos(x[i]/r);
    else
        a = acos(x[i]/r);
    angle.push_back(a);
}

// Sort all vectors by ascending angle vector.
/* Do stuff here! */

// Set up boundary plot data
QVector<float> plot_x, plot_y;
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i {
    if(hits[i]) {
        plot_x.push_back(x[i]);
        plot_y.push_back(y[i]);
    }
}
// curve is a QCPCurve object already existing.
curve->addData(plot_x, plot_y); // Already sorted QVectors
```

**Method 2:** Get `QCustomPlot` `curve->addData(x, y)` member to only plot an "perimeter line" of the scatter plot's `hits`. I have tried using `QCPScatterStyle`, `.setCustomPath`, but have not been successful.

Thank you in advance!
-John

Comment: The context of your question is very particular and that does not help the community to help you, keep in mind that we do not know what you are doing. In your first question, I intuit that you want to order n-vectors using a common criterion, that is, for example, that the indexes of the positions of the n-vectors correspond. Is this correct? If so, what is the criterion, besides I see that you have shown examples of the vector x, e, and what happens with hit?

Comment: According to what I see each pair x and can be associated with an angle, and with respect to that angle you want to order x and y. I am right?

Comment: Well, make array of indices, fill it with [0...N),  make custom comparator which takes your float array(s), sort indices using your comparator, run though your float arrays and swap values

Comment: for the second question, what do you mean by *outer boundary*?

Comment: Yes. I want to order n-vectors using a common criterion. The n-vectors correspond to each other.

Comment: The outer-boundary just means a perimeter plot: Like a polygon or circle. The input is a "grid" of x & y pts. Hits are binary 1 or 0's. There is a max distance that the simulation will let the arrow fly. The majority of the hits are close to the target/bird, & further out x & y are, the less likely there are hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order several vectors using some criteria and all the indices correspond create a new vector that are the indices, and order it, then use those indices to create the new vectors:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <QDebug>

static float calc_angle(float x, float y){
    float r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    float angle = acos(x/r);
    return  y<0 ? -angle : angle;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> hits{0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1};
    std::vector<float> x{-8, -8, -8, -8, -8,  -4, -4, -4, -4, -4};
    std::vector<float> y{-8, -4,  0,  4,  8,  -8, -4,  0,  4,  8};

    Q_ASSERT(x.size() == y.size() && y.size() == hits.size());
    std::vector<int> indexes(x.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

    std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&](const int & i, const int & j) -> bool{
        return calc_angle(x[i], y[i]) < calc_angle(x[j], y[i]);
    });
    QVector<float> plot_x, plot_y;
    QVector<int> new_hits;
    for(const int & index : indexes){
        plot_x<<x[index];
        plot_y<<y[index];
        new_hits<<hits[index];
    }

    qDebug()<<indexes;
    qDebug()<< plot_x;
    qDebug()<<plot_y;
    qDebug()<<new_hits;

    return 0;//a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
std::vector(8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9)
QVector(-4, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -4, -4, -4, -4)
QVector(4, -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, -8, -4, 0, 8)
QVector(0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, eyllanesc. That is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not being clear enough earlier. I should have just phrased it as one question.

Comment: Question 2, was just supposed to be a work around, and get QCP to take a grid of 1's & 0's and plot a line around all 1's. Like a perimeter.

Comment: The sort line returns errors: expected primary-expression before '[' token. expected unqualified-id before 'bool'. Also, what library is std::iota. I couldn't find it so it wouldn't compile.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota : use `#include <numeric>`, What IDE are you using? what is your compiler?

Comment: @JohnShearer if you are using qtcreator enable c++11: `CONFIG += c++11`

Comment: Okay. My IDE is Qt Creator. I will implement that when I get the chance.

Comment: I also got my project to work. I am on another project. But I believe I have used another method to resolve this issue.